# Detecting whether a destructor has been called

Tags: c++, visual-c++, destructor

Im making a board game where the game ends when one piece is destroyed e.g a king dying in chess.

Now I have the possibility of searching through all my objects and seeing that e.g there WERE two pointers to king objects and now there's only one hence game is over and the team with the remaining king won.

I was however wondering if it would instead be possible to say something along the lines of:

```
if(king_destructor is called){
     game over;}
```

But after searching a bit I havent found a way to do that.

More specifically my class structure is:

```
class pieces{}
class king : public pieces{}
```

where pieces is an abstract class and there are derived classes for each individual piece. In the derived class for the 'king' piece there is its destructor.
Otherwise:

```
class game_board{}
```

which is another abstract class which has data members which are pointers to pieces objects. To be exact, I have a map variable which take the position of the piece on the board as the key and a pointer to a piece object as the value.

Finally I have a derived class :

```
class game_rules: public game_board{}
```

it is within this class that I have a function which detects when the game is over.

I experimented with using a static variable that is modified by the 'king' destructor but this is out of the scope of my game_rules class.

Does anyone know whether this is possible?

Comment: Why not make sure the `static` variable is in the correct scope? This approach should work fine.

Comment: Check if the map contains a king? Check if king is a `nullptr`? Have `king` call a callback function when its destructor is invoked? Other than that, you can't access the `king` variable after its destructor is called and I don't think there's a way to check if something was deallocated other than tracking state or checking its pointer is null.

Comment: Checking if the map contains a king i can do but i wondered if there was a more elegant way than looping through the whole map. As far as I'm aware I can't find all the objects of a certain type in a map without looping through every key but if it is possible that would be very interesting !!

Comment: Ill try playing around with the static variable a bit more. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I experimented with using a static variable that is modified by the 'king' destructor but this is out of the scope of my game_rules class.

This seems reasonable. I don't see why scope is a problem. The variable would be private to the `king` class, but with public read-only access.

```
class king : public piece {
    public:
        static unsigned count() { return instance_count; }

    private:
        static unsigned instance_count;
};
```

(Of course, the rest of your class definition would go in there also.)

In the source file for `game_rules`, you would `#include "king.hpp"` (or whatever you named that header file) and get the value of the count of kings with the expression `king::count()`. (A static member function can be called without having an object of that type.) For example, you might write something like the following.

```
if ( king::count() <= 1 ) {
    // Game over
}
```

Comment: but then how could i see the value of the static variable in a function of the game rules class? since its not derived from pieces it is merely derived from a class which contains pieces data members (pointers to those objects).

Comment: You see the value of the static variable by calling the static function. Seeing the static function is (as usual) simply a matter of `#include`ing the appropriate header. If you're not familiar with static member functions, then you should ask for a clarification on how to call `king::count()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several ways you could implement something like this. What struck me from your description is the map from board positions to pointers to pieces. You did not specify what kind of pointer, so I'll improvise. Suppose the map holds [shared pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) to pieces. Then `game_board` could maintain [weak pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) to the `king`s. Instead of searching all of your pieces, you could simply see if the weak pointers are [expired](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/expired). Not only does this tell you if the game is over, but it also tells you who lost.

Comment: i should have said that im just using raw pointers. I've only just started learning about smart pointers so I'll give it a try and see if i can get it working.

Comment: ive been reading more about smart pointers and i was trying to understand your comment fully. What i don't really understand is how i would refer to weak pointers when I use the 'expired' since I'm not naming the pointers although they have a unique ID data member. Also in what sense does a weak pointer being expired also tell you who won? Thanks

Comment: @user3626437 Well, the first step would be to name the pointers. Going back to *"`game_board` could maintain weak pointers to the `king`s"*, in this context, *"maintain"* means *"add members to the class"*, which implies giving those members names of some sort. If your class had looked like `class game_board { std::map<position, std::shared_ptr<piece>> board; }`, then after adding weak pointers, it might look like `class game_board { std::weak_ptr<piece> king1, king2; std::map<position, std::shared_ptr<piece>> board; }`.